# How to fix inverted video on skype?

Tags: video, skype

I just installed 12.10 on my Lenovo y510 laptop. The webcam worked fine while setting up Ubuntu, it also works fine with Google Chat and Cheese. But with Skype 4, the video is inverted 180 degrees. I didn't see any options within Skype to fix it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976566) article and it worked for me.

**1. Rename /usr/bin/skype to /usr/bin/skype.original.**

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/skype /usr/bin/skype.original
```

**2. Create a new /user/bin/skype file.**

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/skype
```

**3. Paste the following:**

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype.original
```

**4. Save & exit gedit.**

**5. Make /usr/bin/skype executable.**

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/skype
```

**6. Start Skype as you normally would.**